# Why make_shared call the destructor even if there are still weak pointer?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, make-shared

From theory, one difference between `make_shared()` and `shared_ptr` is the memory allocation technique. `make_shared()` should use a single block, while `shared_ptr` should use two blocks.

One `make_shared()` drawback should be that memory can't be freed if there is even a single `weak_ptr` alive.

Can someone explain why the output of this program is always the same independently from the function I use to create the `shared_ptr`?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class mc
{
    public:
      mc(int p):p_{p} {std::cerr<<"Constructor"<<std::endl;}
      ~mc() { std::cerr<<"Destructor"<<std::endl;}    
    private:
      int p_;    
};

std::weak_ptr<mc> wp3;

int main()
{
 
    auto sp=std::make_shared<mc>(4);
    auto sp2=sp;
    auto sp3{sp};
    wp3=std::weak_ptr<mc>{sp};
    
    sp2.reset();
    sp3.reset();
    sp.reset();
     
    for (int i =0;i< 5;i++) {std::cerr<<sp.use_count()<<std::endl;}   

    return 0;
}
```

I was expecting the destructor method to be called at the end, since the `weak_ptr` is still alive, why is that not happening?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Even if its memory can't be freed, the object held by a `shared_ptr` will still be destroyed when the (non-weak) refcount reaches zero. Object destruction and memory release are two separate operations that don't need to happen at the same time.

In general, since the "one allocation" behavior of `make_shared` is an optimization, it should not have an observable effect on your code.

Comment: Any way to observe this behavior?

Comment: What exactly do you want to observe? You already observed the object destruction. If you want to observe the memory allocation/deallocation, you either have to hook into your default memory allocator or use a custom allocator via `allocate_shared`.

Comment: @Francesco.S [Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f17d26bbfaabf41e) is your original example modified to use `allocate_shared` with a custom allocator that shows only a single allocation is done that doesn't get freed until after the `weak_ptr` goes out of scope.

Answer (score 2):

Simply making a [`std::weak_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr) refer to a `std::shared_ptr` does not increase the reference count of the object that the `shared_ptr` manages.  The `std::weak_ptr` is just a passive observer until it is locked, returning a new `shared_ptr` which either 1) refers to the shared object incrementing its reference count if it has not expired yet, or else 2) contains `nullptr` if the object has expired.

When a shared object's reference count falls to 0 (ie, no more `std::shared_ptr`s refer to it), the object is destroyed immediately.  In your example, that happens on the call to `sp.reset()`, not when `main()` exits.  You created 3 `shared_ptr` references to an `mc` object, and then you `reset()` those 3 references, thus destroying the object before your `for` loop then printed out the reference count.

```
int main()
{
 
    auto sp=std::make_shared<mc>(4); // object created, refcnt is 1
    auto sp2=sp;  // refcnt becomes 2
    auto sp3{sp}; // refcnt becomes 3
    wp3=std::weak_ptr<mc>{sp}; // refcnt stays 3 !!
    
    sp2.reset(); // refcnt becomes 2
    sp3.reset(); // refcnt becomes 1
    sp.reset();  // refcnt becomes 0, object destroyed, wp3 is now expired !!
     
    for (int i =0;i< 5;i++) {std::cerr<<sp.use_count()<<std::endl;} // refcnt is 0

    return 0;
} // sp, sp2, sp3 are destroyed
```

If what you were expecting were actually true, that a `std::weak` increases a shared object's reference count, that would defeat the whole purpose of `std::weak_ptr`, making it act just like `std::shared_ptr`. `std::weak_ptr` is a "weak" (passive, no active reference) smart pointer, whereas `std::shared_ptr` is a "strong" (active reference) smart pointer.